# Text 2 Speech Application to Read User Activities in Windows OS

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-7, text-to-speech

I am working on an application using c# that will implement normal Text to Speech functionality using the Speech Synthesizer. One other functionality I want to implement is something similar to the Narrator Accessibility tool that comes with the Windows OS. The application should be able to go to background and read out information on what ever the mouse points at in any application.

Does any on know any library I can call or implement, that will make this possible? I am using Visual Studio 2010 Professional.

Thanks

Comment: Please mention the framework, ussing Visual studio 2010 you can develop applications for all the frameworks(if they are installed), sorry if it is too trivial

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [System.Speech](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg145021.aspx) namespace - it should contain everything you will need.

Comment: Implement the Speech functionality is not the problem, its the ability to follow the User's activities in the OS and readout, e.g when he points at the "Start Button', It should say'Start Button'

Comment: @Abubakar Siddiq Ango -  If you want to achieve that functionality, you may have to look more into win32 API's, for more about them go to http://pinvoke.net